# AWS Codepipeline based on Conditional trigger

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I have a repo which has 2 or more directories. Each directory will be built and deployed as individual service in ECS and also 2 AWS Code pipelines are built based on this repo. So when there is a change only in a particular directory then only that Codepipeline has to be triggered automatically. 
May i know how to handle this in AWS ??? 
I have one thought to use GIT Submodules but does AWS support GIT Submodule ??? 
If there is also a better way to do this please suggest one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's under "additional configuration" when you're editing or creating the source:

[image]